# Issue with Upload Macro: How to Make the Upload Macro Paste Data on the last row?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having an issue with the following logic for the upload button macro. The issue is, I want the data to be pasted on the last row of column C and D, and I want the uploaded data to be put right below to the last inputted data on column c and d. Here is the aforementioned code:

```
Sub Upload_file()

Dim FileToOpen As Variant
Dim Openbook As Workbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename
If FileToOpen <> False Then
    Set Openbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    Openbook.Sheets(3).Range("E2:F152893").Copy
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C") & Rows.Count).end(xlup).Row).Filldown
    Openbook.Close False
    
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

I'm having an issue on this part, where it says syntax error.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C") & Rows.Count).end(xlup).Row).Filldown
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & Cells(Rows.Count,"C").end(xlUp).row)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply- I have received a run time error 438: object doesn't support this property or record

Comment: additionally, the code succesfully copy the data- but not paste it

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Upload_file()

    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim Openbook, wb As Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
        Set Openbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
        wb.Activate
        Openbook.Sheets(3).Range("E2:F152893").Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).row)
        Openbook.Close False
    End If
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```